# Deploying mvc project to iis 6.0

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-6, 64-bit

I am trying to deploy my mvc project on windows server 2003 IIS6.

I have enabled the wildcard mapping

.net framework 3.5 sp1 and mvc 1.0 is installed on the machine

I am still getting 404 when I try to access the site

What other steps should I debug to solve this problem?

Ps: Other non-mvc .net project is running fine on the machine

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: I see a lot of references to that article but it is currently not working

Comment: try the cache... 

http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:YMlwk9qxlQoJ:weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/07/22/asp-net-hosting-recommendation-if-you-re-on-a-budget.aspx+http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was not referencing the 64bit version of aspnet_isapi.dll - i am running on win2003 64bit